# format ajax POST data, json into variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

If I need to call a controller like this:

```
 name.php?data={"user":"test","pass":"test"}
```

In order to obtain the information I need, via **.ajax**, I need help setting the variable to be sent with that specific format.

I used to the following code:

```
 var arr = [{
     data: {
      "user" : $("#usuario").val(),
      "pass" : $("#password").val()
 }];
 arr = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

However if doesn't send the right output, I've been said I need to send the variable with the json on it.

```
 function callAjax(url, arr) {
  var response = null;
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: arr, 
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
   response = data;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   response = errorThrown;
},
timeout: 5000
 });
 return response;
 }
```

Any advises?

Best Regards!

Comment: Show your AJAX handler code.

Comment: why not just `$.get('name.php', {user:$('#usuario').val(), ...});`? You shouldn't really be passing raw json in a query parameter. not without url-encoding it, to make sure any url metachars are safely encoded/escaped.

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you a lot!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: it helps, however I cannot find to make this part ?data= the rest is ok

Answer (score 0):

I used .post instead and solved the issue